# Netbeans Ubuntu C++ cannot find include files in release build but can in debug

Tags: gcc, g++, netbeans-8, ubuntu-11.04

I am creating a small command line C/C++ app to convert a binary file to a tab delimited text file after not working with C/C++ for several years.  Netbeans is new to me as well.  The include files below work fine when I build using 'Debug' but when using 'Release' I get the IDE error "Cannot find include file'; The files are flagged as well as lines of code.  The compiler error is 'No such file or directory'.

I have other apps in the work space that do compile with the release tab set.

```
// these are the first code lines in the file    
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// No problem with these
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

I don't notice any differences in properties between the apps that build correctly and this one.

Edit:

I've added the path to the includes, `/usr/include` for C and `/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/` for C++, (I have not done this for other apps and they compile) and the error colors for the release includes went from red to yellow and only two lines in the code had red underlines. size_type and npos with the error "unable to find identifiers:

```
void replaceExt(std::string& s, const std::string& newExt) {

    std::string::size_type i = s.rfind('.', s.length()); // size_type

    if (i != std::string::npos) {                        //npos
        s.replace(i + 1, newExt.length(), newExt);
    }
}
```

The compiler produced this error message:

```
gcc -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/c++/4.9.2 -I/usr/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:9:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/cstdlib:41:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/c++config.h>
```

Final Edit

It didn't appear right that NetBeans would not have the path to the standard includes so I created a new C++ project, accepted all the default preferences, and copied the all the code except main from the failed project to the new one checking to see if it would compile.  Lastly I copied main and found that it builds in both release and debug with no errors.

I don't have any idea what went wrong, but I've found the fix.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't appear right that NetBeans would not have the path to the standard includes so I created a new C++ project, accepted all the default preferences, and copied the all the code except main from the failed project to the new one checking to see if it would compile. Lastly I copied main and found that it builds in both release and debug with no errors.

I don't have any idea what went wrong, but I've found the fix.